# Does sequence ${ s }_{ n }=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \frac { 1 }{ { 1+k }^{ 2 } } } $ converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm reviewing some Calculus 1 convergence stuff. I want to decide wether ${ s }_{ n }:=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \frac { 1 }{ { 1+k }^{ 2 } }  } $

is convergent or not.
Since the sequence is monotnically increasing and has an upper and lower bound it is convergent, but im failing to make the right estimates

Comment: What do you mean by "failing to make the right estimates"? You are saying it yourself, monotonicity and boundedness imply convergence, so you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do much more than proving it is convergent (trivial by comparison with $1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}=1+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$), you can compute $\lim_{n\to +\infty}s_n$ in a explicit way. Since
$$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^+,\qquad \frac{1}{k^2+1} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(k x)}{k}\,e^{-x}\,dx \tag{A}$$
follows by integration by parts, and $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(k x)}{k}$ is the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave, which is $2\pi$-periodic and equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ over the interval $x\in(0,2\pi)$, we have
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2+1}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\pi-x}{2}\left[e^{-x}+e^{-(x+2\pi)}+\ldots\right]\,dx=\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\pi-x}{2}\,e^{-x}\,dx\tag{B} $$
and by integration by parts
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2+1}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi}}\cdot\frac{(\pi+1)e^{-2\pi}+(\pi-1)}{2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi\coth\pi-1}{2}}.\tag{C}$$
$(C)$ is also a consequence of the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula), since the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) and the [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) are conjugated via the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$
0<\sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty }\frac { 1 }{ { 1+k }^{ 2 } }\leq \sum _{ k=1 }^{ \infty }\frac {1}{k^2}.
$$
You should be able to tell whether the last series has a finite value.

Comment: I can use comparison test because im looking at $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sum _{  }^{ n }{ { a }_{ n } }  } =\sum _{  }^{ \infty  }{ { a }_{ n } } $? because im initally just lookin at a finite sum

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the comparison test of series.

Answer (score 2):

Note $k^2+1>k^2$. So $\frac{1}{k^2+1}<\frac{1 }{k^2}$. And now use comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

1) Sequence is monotonically increasing .

2)Need to find an upper bound:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{1+k^2}\le$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2}$.

Consider:

$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2} \le$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)} =$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}[\dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k+1}]=$

$1 - \dfrac{1}{n}.$

Bounded above.

Sum converges.